# PWA development in localhost

Tags: laravel, progressive-web-apps

Currently, I am trying to make my website support PWA. After implementing it, it works on the browser from the desktop where the button to install it is available on the address bar, but when I tested it on my mobile locally, somehow it won't prompt the "Add to home screen" popup.

Could the reason be that I run it locally, as it only uses the HTTP protocol? Or I missed something in order to set up for that popup specifically? My website is on Laravel 7.

Hope anyone could help enlighten me with this issue.
Thank you.

UPDATE: Solved it. Apparently by running the website locally with exposed public port using ngrok with HTTPS protocol, I am able to simulate how the app will behave on the mobile and the "Add to home screen" popup finally appeared.

Answer (score 2):

PWAs by definition need HTTPS connections to be installed and run properly (as you said). On your development machine you are making use of the exception for "localhost". On your mobile device, you are not accessing the site locally as it is not hosted on the device itself.

Comment: That makes sense. I noticed that there are some videos that demonstrates port forwarding from the browser to test out the PWA app for mobile devices. Should this behave properly like how it would on HTTPS protocol?